# js datatables in pagination

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables

I am facing an issue in datatables. I want to display my all pages data in tables. etc `page1` `page2`

API's data

```
https://examp.com/api/v2/email?per_page=100&page=1

https://examp.com/api/v2/email?per_page=100&page=2
```

my code

```
     //datatable
     $('#example').dataTable({
      "searching": false,     
      "bSort": false ,
      "bInfo": false, //show entries
      "bLengthChange": false, //top entries
      "bDestroy": true

     });
```

what should i do? anyone help me?

Comment: https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/83/how-to-pagination-with-ajax

Comment: Hi, you can follow this example [example](https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/select_rows.html)